# Word for change in velocity

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, analogy

Is there a good word for change in velocity, but not over time? That is, position is to displacement as velocity is to what?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure the only terms for a change in velocity are *acceleration* and *deceleration* (and "deceleration" is just a special case of acceleration.)

Comment: @MT_Head Acceleration doesn't fit because acceleration = change-in-velocity/time. I'm basically looking for a word for acceleration*time.

Comment: *acceleration* * *time* is the definition of velocity. v=a*t ( + v0) just as displacement(s) = 1/2 a*t^2 + v0*t + s0

Comment: @Jim acceleration x time is NOT the definition of velocity.  It is equivalent to "change in velocity", which is what Arafinwe is seeking a single word for.

Comment: The OP is looking for a word that describes a change of velocity without time... which, as far as I can tell, means that a single object would have two (or more) velocities _at the same time_.  I don't see how that's possible, assuming that we're talking about a single object.  Perhaps "teleportation"?

Comment: @MT_Head I think you have misunderstood the question.  He/she wants the difference between the velocity at one moment and the velocity at another moment; just like displacement is the difference between the position at one moment and the position at another moment.  I don't believe there IS such a word; I would always just say "change in velocity".  It's a really good question though.

Comment: @DavidWallace - I believe there _is_ such a word.  And that word is... **acceleration**.  If you subtract velocity X from velocity Y, what you get is the force required to produce the change between them.  And we call that force... wait for it...

Comment: I should restate: actually, if you subtract velocities, the answer is another velocity.  But if we are talking about an actual, real object, the subtraction is meaningless if time is left out; it's an arithmetic exercise with no real-world application.  In the real world, objects change their velocity over time.

Comment: [This might be useful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v), though...

Comment: I think @MT_Head's link should [point here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v_(physics)).

Comment: @coleopterist - You're right - what happened was that "delta-V" was rattling around in my head from a misspent youth reading the Shuttle manual and lots of science fiction, but I couldn't remember the actual term.  As soon as I did remember it, the main landing page brought on a flood of nostalgia and I didn't think to disambiguate.

Comment: @MT_Head I know the feeling :) Please convert your link into an answer. I reckon that it's the only real possibility.

Comment: @DavidWallace- Yes, I agree, for non-zero initial velocity, a*t is the change in velocity.

Comment: Should we be debating physics on ELU at all?

Comment: @Kris - [That's a strange question for you to ask...](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55655/is-low-speed-finally-proving-its-merit)  <g>

Comment: @MT_Head: :) Good you remember that! However, my question there is the other way around, about language in the context of science. This is essentially a science question, not about language. See below: **Δv** is a *notation*, not a *word in the English language*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard term for a difference of velocities is **delta-v**.

[Quoting Wikipedia (I know, I know!)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v_%28physics%29):

> In general physics, delta-v is simply the change in velocity. The Greek letter delta is a standard mathematical symbol to represent change (and can be thought of as a fulcrum with a beginning and ending state).
>   Depending on the situation, delta-v can be referred to as a spatial vector (Δv) or scalar (Δv). In both cases it is equal to the acceleration (vector or scalar) integrated over time:

(Sadly, I don't know enough TeX to include the equations here.)

The term "delta-V" has [another, closely-related meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v) that brings back a good deal of nostalgia, in this week of watching the *Endeavour* fly to its final home:

> In astrodynamics a Δv or delta-v (literally "change in velocity") is a scalar which takes units of speed. It is a measure of the amount of "effort" that is needed to change from one trajectory to another by making an orbital maneuver.
>   Delta-v is produced by the use of propellant by reaction engines to produce a thrust that accelerates the vehicle.

Comment: Δv or delta-v are not *words*! And they do *not* say "but not over time", either. Should I down vote the answer or vote to close the Q. as off-topic?

Comment: Why are they not words? Their origin is as a mathemtical placeholder, but in many contexts they are, indeed, used like words. "Find the delta-v for this equation". I think it's a good parallel for "displacement".

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan **Δv** is a mathematical notation independent of language -- it's therefore not an English word.

Comment: Δv might a mathematical notation independent of language, but "delta-v" is a English word derived from that notation. "delta", in general, is used to mean "a difference" or "the set of differences". Both "delta" and "delta-v" can be found in some dictionaries (though not all) and in popular usage.

Comment: @Kris △v is not a word, and thus isn't really what I was looking for. However, this is the first answer which fits the definition; it _does_ mean "but not over time". Furthermore, I think it highly unlikely that there is a single word which fits the definition. Thus, although this is not an English word as such, this will be the accepted answer unless in the rare possibility that an actual word comes along which fits the definition.

Comment: @Arafinwe - Although this is my own answer, I have to dispute your statement that 'it *does* mean "but not over time"'.  The physics definition actually says "it is equal to the acceleration (vector or scalar) integrated over time".  I don't think you're going to find a word that does NOT include some time aspect, because (as I said earlier) that would be a meaningless construct.

Comment: @MT_Head That's **precisely** what I wanted actually- acceleration *integrated* over time. When I said I wanted "acceleration*time" that means "acceleration integrated over time" in the simple case of constant acceleration. "Acceleration integrated over time" simply refers to the more general case.

Comment: @Arafinwe - Excellent!  I had a feeling we must be talking past each other; I'm glad we eventually arrived.

Answer (score 2):

Several disctionaries define acceleration without reference to direction of change

According to [YourDictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/acceleration):

> Acceleration is a change in the rate of motion, speed or action.

[Oxford](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/accelerate?view=uk) defines “accelerate” as

> *Physics*   undergo a change in velocity

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/acceleration) says

> the rate of increase of speed or **the rate of change of velocity**

While acceleration is usually used to refer to an increase, it seems possible that it could be expressed as a negative number to show a decrease.

These are clearly general definitions and may or may not reflect the views of the scientific or engineering communities.

Comment: (-1) No, this is incorrect. The problem is not regarding direction, rather it is regarding the time aspect. The question was asking about change, not **rate of** change.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *[stasis](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/stasis)*

> condition of balance among various forces; motionlessness

However, I think the analogy would be

> position: displacement:: stasis: velocity

Comment: That only really works for *lack of change* in velocity, not *change* in velocity.

Answer (score -1):

[*Acceleration*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acceleration), as defined in Wiktionary:

> 1. The act of accelerating, or the state of being accelerated; increase of motion or action…
> 2. The amount by which a speed or velocity increases …

Comment: (-1) No, this is incorrect. Acceleration is defined as the derivative of velocity with respect to time; I am asking about just the change in velocity. See also the comments on the original question.