# Term for the error in the reason is because

Tags: expressions, style-manuals

A common error is to say *the reason is because* instead of *the reason
is that.* Is there an attested or unattested term for this kind of
error?  (I'll leave it open exactly what kind of error it is.)

(Or, if you insist, is there, *on the controversial assumption that this
is in fact an error,* a term for its kind?  Please do not take this
question as an invitation to attack this assumption.)

Comment: See also: **Is 'low speed' finally proving its merit?** https://english.stackexchange.com/q/55655/14666

Answer (score 1):

[***The reason is because***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34396/is-it-correct-to-say-the-reason-is-because) (as previously queried on ELU in that link) is a form of ***redundancy*** (perhaps ***tautology, pleonasm***), because ***the reason*** and ***because*** both convey the sense of ***why***, what **causes** something to be the case.

Pedants will thus say you should use either ***the reason is X*** or *[it] **is because X***, but not both. But many native speakers routinely ignore such advice - it's certainly not universally considered an "error".

Comment: As far as I can see, this explanation would also apply to _the reason
why,_ which, I think, is not erroneous.

Comment: @Toothrot: So you think extending *The reason is X* to *The reason **why** is X*  is "okay", but you're not happy about extending it to *The reason is **because** X*. I can't really see that argument.

Comment: I think it's more complicated than that.

Comment: Well, yes. [Here's a link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=opdWDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA801&dq=%22the+reason+why+is+because%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiP64_H683kAhVCtnEKHWYcBP4Q6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20reason%20why%20is%20because%22&f=false) to an extended discussion in *Webster's Dictionary of English Usage* concerning the usage ***the reason is because***. Which they point out was used by Bacon, Swift, Hemmingway,... (as they dryly put it, ***not bad company for a writer***). But essentially it's all just a matter of (potentially changing over time) ***idiomacy***.

Comment: Interesting!  Unfortunately, I could only see the first page.

Comment: Note that I'm trying not to go overboard "attacking your assumption" that the usage *is in fact an error*. But it's not. I can't get to the next page of that link myself, but they've obviously said most of what they have to say on the page as linked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98619/discussion-between-toothrot-and-fumblefingers).